# bash: How to prevent expand /* in read?

Tags: bash

I need to parse some PHP files, and they contain comments like `/**/`
But:

```
read line <<< "/*"
echo $line
```

I want the variable `line` to have `/*`, not `/bin /boot /cdrom /core /dev /etc /home...`.

Comment: The idiomatic way to read a line without losing any characters is `IFS= read -r line`

Answer (score 2):

The variable actually *does* hold exactly `/*`. Your `echo` prints `/bin /boot …` because the shell expands *unquoted* `$line` just before it runs `echo`. In Bash expanding an unquoted variable involves word splitting and filename generation (globbing).

Double-quote the variable:

```bash
read line <<< "/*"
echo "$line"
```

[Get used to double-quoting all variables.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)

Other things to improve:

- [`read`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/108618)
- [`echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618)

Comment: Thanks for `echo`.
But how to do a replacement? `echo "$(line/*/!)"` does not work.

Comment: @VladimirKalachikhin This looks like a separate problem. One question per question please. Take our short [tour] to see how the site is designed to work. Let's not go [chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually
[globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)),
rather than expansion.

This is a method of solving your question :

```
$ #disable glob (noglob)
$ set -f
$ echo $line
/*
$ #re-enable glob
$ set +f
```

Useful reading :
[Stop shell wildcard character expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion/11456496#11456496)

Comment: Thanks for globbing.
But I still can't do a replacement too. `echo $(line/*/!)`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all and sorry for my mistakes.
Yes, the problem with globbing (as a special case of expansion?)
With replacements correct code is

```
read line <<< "/* string */"
echo "${line//"*"/!}"
```

or

```
set -f
echo ${line//"*"/!}
set +f
```

but `"*"` (with quotes)  is necessary, despite `set -f`

Comment: If a bash script does not work as expected, I always try to run it with option `-x`: Usually you see what's going on. In you case you would see that the assignment is correct,, and that `echo` gets the "globbed" list. see also https://serverfault.com/q/16204/407952

Comment: Again, please make yourself familiar with our [tour]. Super user is not a discussion forum. Your answer copies solutions from other answers when it comes to the problem in the question; and it introduces your solution to a problem not present in the question. If the latter problem was in the question, answers would probably address it as well. I totally support dividing complex problems to orthogonal parts, IMO you did well asking for a simple case first. But the next problem requires a next question. Comments or self-answers are not to add follow-up problems.